Example of a Quasitopological Group
What are examples of quasitopological groups which are not topological groups?
Specifically, this would be a group with a topology such that the maps $y \mapsto a \cdot y$, $x \mapsto x \cdot a$ are continuous for fixed $a$, and $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is also continuous, but $(x,y) \mapsto x \cdot y$ is not continuous.

Edit: Indeed, here's a much simpler example. Take any infinite group $G$ and equip it with the cofinite topology. (Open subsets are those which are either empty or have a finite complement.) Any bijection $G \to G$ is necessarily continuous, which proves that $G$ is a quasitopological group because inversion and multiplication by a fixed element are bijections. But $G$ is not a topological group. One can show this explicitly, but an abstract argument would be that $G$ is $T_1$, but not $T_2$, but any topological group which is $T_1$ is automatically $T_2$. I will still leave up the original answer below, because the example below is actually used as a quasitopological group, whereas this easier example seems more "constructed".

I am sure much easier examples exist, but this examples appears "in nature", in the sense that it is useful and that it is not specifically constructed to give an example of a quasitopological group in which multiplication is not continuous.
In number theory, there's the theory of local fields. (There are also archimedean local fields, namely $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$, but we will focus on non-archimedean ones.) One important example of a local field is the field of $p$-adic numbers $\Bbb Q_p$. Another example is the field of Laurent series over a finite field. for example $\Bbb F_p((t))$. All these fields carry a natural topology.
Going beyond this classical case, there are also higher-dimensional local fields (which are not local fields in the classical sense). The easiest way to obtain a higher-dimensional local field is to start with a local field in the classical sense, i.e. $\Bbb Q_p$ or $\Bbb F_p((t))$ and take the field of formal Laurent series over it, so that we get something like $\Bbb Q_p((t))$ or $\Bbb F_p((t_1))((t_2))$. There are several topologies on a higher dimensional local field that are used, but the following is important and it is called the "higher topology".
Let $K$ be a field equipped with a Hausdorff topology such that addition $+:K \times K \to K$ is continuous and for each $a \in K$, multiplication by $a$ is a continuous map from $K$ to $K$.
Then we can define a topology on $K((t))$ as follows:
For any $\Bbb Z$-indexed sequence of open neighborhoods of $0$ in $K$ given by $(U_i)_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}$ such that there exists an $N$ such that $U_n=K$ for all $n\geq N$, we define a subset of $K((t))$ given by
$$\left\{\sum_{i} a_i t^i \in K((t))\ \middle|\ \forall i: a_i \in U_i \right\}$$
We declare this collection of subsets of $K((t))$ to be a basis of neighborhoods for $0$ and define a neighborhood basis for all other elements by translating them.
If we start with $K=\Bbb Q_p$ or $K=\Bbb F_p((t))$, then the resulting topology on $K((t))$ will not make $K((t))$ into a topological field, although $K$ in that case is a topological field. Neither inversion nor multiplication will be continuous, but for any fixed element $a \in K((t))$, multiplication by $a$ is continuous.
To get a "good" topology (i.e. one in which inversion is continuous) on the unit group $K((t))^\times$ from this, we can apply the standard trick that is also used to topologize the units of a topological ring. Embed $K((t))^\times$ into the product $K((t)) \times K((t))$ via $K((t))^\times \to K((t)) \times K((t)), u \mapsto (u,u^{-1})$. The resulting topology makes $K((t))^\times$ into a quasitopological group such that multiplication is not continuous (for $K=\Bbb Q_p$ or $K=\Bbb F_p((t))$).

This is a very interesting answer
